# $\min_{p_i} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{p_i}{r_i (1 - \frac{ap_i}{r_i})} s.t. \sum_{p_i}^{N} = 1 $

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

$$\min_{p_i} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{p_i}{r_i (1 - \frac{ap_i}{r_i})}$$
$$s.t. \sum_{i=1}^{N} p_i= 1 $$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $r_i \in \mathbb{R}$ $\forall i$ 
, $p_i > 0$, 
$r_i>a p_i$

I tried to solve it using Lagrangian method, but could not find the result.

Comment: Can $p_i<0$? If so, this might not always have an answer

Comment: You should put conditions $p_i>0$ and $r_i>ap_i$.

Comment: All $r_i$s can be infinitely large, and then the formula in question will be $0$, and that is the minimum, unless there is another condition.

Comment: $r_i$ is a parameter that we cannot change